# `muti_json` gem version conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4.2

we are using `clever-ruby` gem which is already installed in my project. 
Now I am working on one feature where I need to store the values in server-side `cookies` when I stored that value in cookies at that time `CookieOverflow` error is occured.

So I changed the session store to `active_record_store`. While installing this gem there is one gem dependence i.e `multi_json` which require version `>= 1.11.2, ~> 1.11`.

Now `clever-ruby` gem required a version of the `multi_json` is `1.1` and `active_record_store` gem require `>= 1.11.2, ~> 1.11`.

**Error:**

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":
In Gemfile:
activerecord-session_store was resolved to 1.1.3, which depends on
  multi_json (~> 1.11, >= 1.11.2)

clever-ruby was resolved to 0.13.0, which depends on
  multi_json (~> 1.10.0)
```

Because of this issue, I am not able to set up the `activerecord-session_store` gem.

Is there any way to manage the two different version of `multi_json` gem?
Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**You just have to update `clever-ruby` gem to version so it also can work with newer `multi_json` gem. Make sure to look out for any breaking changes.**

If this is not possible because of breaking changes(which seems unlikely after a quick look in its changelog) than you will have to downgrade `activerecord-session_store` gem so the version of `multi_json` required by it gets matched with that of `clever-ruby v0.13.0`.

First option should work, if version for clever ruby is locked in gemfile remove that and run **`bundle update clever-ruby`**

Comment: thanks for your answer. But the thing is if I downgrade the `activerecord-session_store` still these gem doesn't support the `multi_json` v1.1. I checked the lowest version of `multi_json` gem

Comment: Than you have to update `clever-ruby` whats issue in that?